# How to test method that uses third-party code

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have got a class that uses other object — MultinomialNB from `scikit-learn`. This class has got a function that uses this object and I want to test it.

What is a proper way of testing it? Should I mock out objects that I import from other libraries? I guess that it would take me much more time than when writing this function.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__():
        self.model = MultinomialNB()
        self.extr = FeatureExtractor()

    ... other methods

    def get_most_coefficient_features(self):
        if len(self.model.coef_) != len(self.model.classes_):
            raise Exception("Different number of model features than coefs.")

        result = dict()
        for i, target in enumerate(self.model.classes_): 
            feats = sorted(zip(self.extr.features, self.model.coef_[i]), key=lambda t: t[1])
            result[target] = feats
        return result
```

Should I test it like that? (actually I cannot because I cannot override the "coef_" because it is a property)

```
def test_get_most_coefficient_features(self):
    myclass_obj = MyClass()
    myclass_obj.extr.features = ["F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5"]
    myclass_obj.model.classes_ = ["True", "False"]
    myclass_obj.model.coef_ = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
    res = myclass_obj.get_most_coefficient_features()
    exp_res = dict({"True": ["F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5"], "False": ["F5", "F4", "F3", "F2", "F1"]})
    self.assertEqual(exp_res, res)
```

Comment: My answer would depend on the criticality of this function.

Comment: Please refine your question.  At the moment, it appears to include needing a tutorial on software testing, which is far beyond the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mixture of an algorithmic core and some interactions with the external library.  Due to this mixed nature it seems to require some mocking to deal with he interactions for unit-testing, and I understand your question such that you want to know whether it is worth the trouble.

The algorithm is complex enough (I would say) to justify *some* effort for testing.  However, whether testing the original code with the necessary mocking is worth it depends (as was mentioned in the comments) on the criticality of the function.

But, the effort for mocking can in this particular case be eliminated by a simple design change: You can separate the algorithm you want to test from the interactions with the external library:

```
def calc_most_coefficient_features(self, features, model_coefs, model_classes):
    if len(model_coefs) != len(model_classes):
        raise Exception("Different number of model features than coefs.")

    result = dict()
    for i, target in enumerate(model_classes): 
        feats = sorted(zip(features, model.coefs[i]), key=lambda t: t[1])
        result[target] = feats
    return result

def get_most_coefficient_features(self):
    return self.calc_most_coefficient_features(
        self.extr.features, self.model.coef_, self.model.classes_)
```

You can now test `calc_most_coefficient_features` using unit-testing, and test `get_most_coefficient_features` using integration testing.